# Angular website making requests to internal API

Tags: angular, typescript, http, https

I have an Angular website that connects to an internal (non public facing) REST API. Obviously during testing this all works fine as the client browser is on the same network as the internal API. As soon as I want to make the website publicly accessible, the website is no longer able to consume the internal API as the requests are coming from the client browser (and not the backend server hosting the website).

The question I have is is there a way to make the API requests from the backend server hosting the Website? I am not really sure how to proceed with this short of making the internal API publicly accessible.

On the network tab in the browser I can see the request being made from the browser:

[image]

Ignore the response as this request was internal. The problem is is that this URL that is being accessed is an internal URL. Is there a way to make angular do this request from the backend server that is hosting the website.

See this rough network diagram:
[image]

The line in red appears to be what is happening.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me.

Comment: We need some code to better undestand what's going on here. It could be VPN issue as it could be some URL/IP issue.

Comment: It may be a CORS issue too. What do you see in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty typical use case for a reverse proxy. Depending on what kind of server software you're using it may already have this feature available for you and just needs to be configured. Nginx is able to create a reverse proxy (not a paid endorsement, it's just great software!).

Comment: Ahh, That seems like a possible solution to this issue. We are using IIS but that should support setting up a reverse proxy.